# Eclipse 4.4 quit unexpectedly on MacOS - works when run from terminal

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna, macos-mojave

I'm using a 2017 MacBook Pro with macOS Mojave version 10.14.3. I'm trying to install Eclipse 4.4 in order to use the GGTS plugin.

I downloaded the installation file from eclipse home page and unzipped it to a folder named "eclipse", by default.

I moved Eclipse.app to the Applications folder, but when I start the program, it showed an error dialog saying Eclipse quit unexpectedly.

However, when I run eclipse from the terminal, it worked out just fine, so I'm confused what's the underlying problem with this.

Here's the log

```
Process:               eclipse [1381]
Path:                  /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
Identifier:            org.eclipse.platform.ide
Version:               4.4.0 (4.4.0.I20140606-1215)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           eclipse [1381]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-02-01 15:25:06.911 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.3 (18D42)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.0 (14Y674)
Anonymous UUID:        982D7B17-3CD6-65E7-C0E9-80F38A781B0B

Sleep/Wake UUID:       AFBA951A-5AAC-4A65-A546-79D101B90607

Time Awake Since Boot: 2600 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000034
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [1381]

VM Regions Near 0x34:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100000000-0000000100004000 [   16K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4b48c11b CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName + 13
1   org.eclipse.platform.ide        0x000000010000306b findSymbol + 66
2   org.eclipse.platform.ide        0x00000001000017f6 original_main + 1572
3   org.eclipse.platform.ide        0x0000000100001eb5 main + 1230
4   org.eclipse.platform.ide        0x0000000100001090 start + 52

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff788a53f8 start_wqthread + 0
1   ???                             0x0000000054485244 0 + 1414025796

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff788a53f8 start_wqthread + 0
1   ???                             0x0000000000001703 0 + 5891

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00006000002002c0  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x6974696e49746573  rdx: 0x0000000000000006
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x00006000002002c0  rbp: 0x00007ffeefbff970  rsp: 0x00007ffeefbff960
   r8: 0x736772416c616974   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x00007ffeefbff7f0  r11: 0x00007fff4b48c10e
  r12: 0x00000001000043f8  r13: 0x0000600002608060  r14: 0x00006000002002c0  r15: 0x0000600000c04090
  rip: 0x00007fff4b48c11b  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x00007fffa412ec88

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000170
Trap Number:     133
```

I've been searching for solutions everywhere but haven't found any. If you neeed more information about the error, or have any suggestion, please let me know. This is getting rather frustrating for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to an incorrect installation (see Eclipse bug [390071](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=390071)).

Eclipse 4.4 (Luna) was not a proper macOS application. You must move the complete Eclipse directory to /Applications rather than just Eclipse.app

Starting from Eclipse 4.5 (Mars) Eclipse is packaged as a proper app.